# Would a "relevant to" vote system work for cross-site answer sourcing?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, cross-posting

Listening to the podcast #2 and the fact that there can be some questions that are valid for numerous sites. In the interests of getting good answers, would it be useful to have an "also relevant to" system that allows the question to be voted on for inclusion on other sites?

Consider I ask the question on SO but someone thinks that the answer might also be useful from the Programmers site (rather than just off topic), so we vote to include it there too, then answers are sourced from both sites.

I'm just thinking in type, really, but it seems like it *might* be useful.

Comment: Interesting.  Another, but more complicated to implement, idea: Real crossposting.  Someone asks a recording question on Music, the mods link it to Audio Recording, and it's shown on both sites with all the answers all together (i.e., it's still just a single post).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this feature would be worth the extra complexity. There aren't that many questions that it's reasonable to cross-post in the first place. Significantly, there are far fewer questions that are worthy of cross-posting than questions whose authors think they are worthy of cross-posting, so anything that makes cross-posting easier is to be treated with deep suspicion.

As a reader, if you're mostly interested in one site, but also in related topics on other sites, you can set up a [filter on the hub site](https://stackexchange.com/filters/) that includes specific tags on all or a few sites.